# Need help to solve challenging Data structure problem

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I came across this problem where given an array of integers, tell if the sequence of
integers will exit the array from left, right or
deadend. You enter the array from the left and move
N indices(where N is the value of the integer) in the
specified direction(positive is right, negative
is left)

```
Examples
[1,1,1] -> Exits Right
[1,-2]=> Exits Left
[2,0,-1]-> Deadends
[2,5,1,-2,0]-> Exits Right
```

One solution which comes to my mind is if value of all integers are positive then
Exits Right or Exits Left. However this solution does not cover all the scenario.
I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate conditions that deem direction? `1, -2` is left but `2, 0, -1` is deadend.

Comment: Yes, so input array is [1,-2], at index 0 we have 1 which is positive so we move right 1 index, at index 1 we have negative number so we move to the left by 2 steps as value of the number is 2 at index 1. When index is [2,0,-1] at index 0 we have number 2 and it is positive so we move 2 index ahead and reach at index 2 which is -1, as number is negative we have to move left by 1 index as value at that index is 1. I hope the explaination is clear

Comment: What if array is like this: `[2,5,0,1,-2,0]`?

Comment: In that case its Deadends at index 2 which is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226588/discussion-between-paritosh-m-and-rajesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

- Create a variable to hold index position and initialize it with first value
- Loop over array and on every iteration, compute new value of `index` by adding value of pointed index.
- At the end of loop, check:

  - `Right`: If `index` >= array.length`
  - `Left`: if `index < 0`
  - `Deadend`: If `index` is in bounds

Based on this, below is an example using Javascript:

```js
function printDirection(arr) {
  let index = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /**
     * Below condition covers following cases:
     * 1. If the value is undefined. This will happen if index is out of bound
     * 2. If value is 0. In this case, `index` will never change and remaining iterations can be skipped
     */
    if (!arr[index]) break;
    index += arr[index]
  }
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    console.log('Exit Right')
  } else if (index < 0) {
    console.log('Exit Left')
  } else {
    console.log('Deadend')
  }
}

const data = [
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, -2],
  [2, 0, -1],
  [2, 5, 1, -2, 0],
]
data.forEach((arr) => printDirection(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some hacky golang:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func WhereIsTheExit(arr []int) {
  
  if (len(arr) == 0) {
    fmt.Println("No elements")
    return
  } 

  i := arr[0]

  for p := 1; p < len(arr); p++ {

    fmt.Printf("Current value: %d\n", i)

    if (i > len(arr) - 1 || i < 0) {
      break
    }

    i += arr[i]

    fmt.Printf("Next value: %d\n", i)
  }

  if (i >= len(arr)) {
    fmt.Println("====> right")
  } else if (i < 0) {
    fmt.Println("====> left")
  } else {
    fmt.Println("====> deadend")
  }
}

func main() {

  empty := []int{}
  deadend := []int{1,2,0,-3}
  deadend2 := []int{1,0,-1}
  right := []int{2,0,3,0,0}
  right2 := []int{1,2,0,4,0,2,7,1}
  left := []int{1,-2}
  left2 := []int{1,2,0,3,0,0,-10}

  WhereIsTheExit(empty)
  WhereIsTheExit(deadend)
  WhereIsTheExit(deadend2)
  WhereIsTheExit(right)
  WhereIsTheExit(right2)
  WhereIsTheExit(left)
  WhereIsTheExit(left2)
}
```

Try out: https://play.golang.org/p/KU4mapYf_b3

Comment: Updated it based on @Rajesh answer